# Is there a way to match the parameters to a Rust macro?

Tags: rust, macros, match, guard

Consider the following code:

```rust
trait Trait {
    fn x(&self) -> u32;
}

struct A {}
impl Trait for A {
    fn x(&self) -> u32 {
        10
    }
}

struct B {}
impl Trait for B {
    fn x(&self) -> u32 {
        20
    }
}

struct C {
    created_time: u64,
}

impl Trait for C {
    fn x(&self) -> u32 {
        30
    }
}

impl C {
    pub fn new() -> C {
        C { created_time: 1000 } // for simplicity
    }
}

macro_rules! create {
    ($type:ident) => {
        match stringify!($type) {
            "C" => Box::new(C::new()) as Box<dyn Trait>,
            _ => Box::new($type {}) as Box<dyn Trait>,
        }
    };
}

fn main() {
    let a: Box<dyn Trait> = create!(A);
    let b: Box<dyn Trait> = create!(B);
    let c: Box<dyn Trait> = create!(C);

    assert_eq!(a.x(), 10);
    assert_eq!(b.x(), 20);
    assert_eq!(c.x(), 30);
}
```

If you ask the compiler to expand the macro, this resolves to:

```rust
let a: Box<dyn T> =
    match "A" {
        "C" => Box::new(C::new()) as Box<dyn T>,
        _ => Box::new(A{}) as Box<dyn T>,
    };
let b: Box<dyn T> =
    match "B" {
        "C" => Box::new(C::new()) as Box<dyn T>,
        _ => Box::new(B{}) as Box<dyn T>,
    };
let c: Box<dyn T> =
    match "C" {
        "C" => Box::new(C::new()) as Box<dyn T>,
        _ => Box::new(C{}) as Box<dyn T>,
    };
```

and this explains nicely why the compiler gives the following error when trying to compile it:

```
error[E0063]: missing field `created_time` in initializer of `C`
  --> mwe.rs:29:27
   |
29 |             _ => Box::new($type { }) as Box<dyn T>,
   |                           ^^^^^ missing `created_time`
...
37 |     let c: Box<dyn T> = create!(C);
   |                         ---------- in this macro invocation

error: aborting due to previous error
```

However, I had expected the compiler to notice the `match "C" { "C" => ..., _ => ... }` case and drop the second clause because it can't ever be run anyhow. Sadly it didn't and instead complained about the second (impossible) clause being impossible to compile.

I also tried replacing the `match` with `if` in the macro as follows, but to no avail:

```rust
macro_rules! create {
    ($type:ident) => {
        if stringify!($type) == "C" {
            Box::new(C::new()) as Box<dyn T>
        } else {
            Box::new($type { }) as Box<dyn T>
        }
    }
}
```

leads to

```rust
let c: Box<dyn T> =
    if "C" == "C" { Box::new(C::new()) as Box<dyn T> }
    else { Box::new(C{}) as Box<dyn T> };
```

with the same error as the `match` attempt.

Hopeful that Haskell's guard pipe syntax would somehow work in Rust, I finally also tried the following:

```rust
macro_rules! create {
    ($type:ident) | (stringify!($type) == "C") => {
        Box::new(C::new()) as Box<dyn T>
    },
    ($type:ident) | (stringify!($type) != "C") => {
        Box::new($type { }) as Box<dyn T>
    },
}
```

but that gave an `error: no rules expected the token '|'`

---

Which ultimately leads me back to the question in the title:

Is there a way to add "guards" to the macro rules to tell the compiler "Only run A if this parameter is passed, or run B on something else" ?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to accomplish with all of this? It seems to me the easiest would be to add the `new` method to all 3 types and always use that. Also your statement: "Sadly it didn't and instead complained about the second (impossible) clause being impossible to compile." is incorrect. Rust cannot determine at compile time whether certain arms/branches will be taken or not and the code within these arms must still be syntactically correct *even* if they are never called

Comment: @sshashank124 Indeed; I want to save myself from making `new` functions for structs that don't need it (because it doesn't have fields or they are all public), so I tried to make a helper macro, but I guess that's not possible then.

Comment: Yeah personally I would say a new function doesn't really take more than 2-3 lines and is universally understood in Rust. I'm not sure replacing that with a macro wrapper that not everyone might be familiar with is necessarily better. Again, just my personal opinion

Comment: You could also derive the Default trait for your structs which would give you the benefit of less code and also a uniform way to instantiate instances without arguments

Comment: @mcarton's answer is probably the most effective one.  However it seems like a Rust anti-pattern to set things up like this. Why would you not create a macro that applies a template to each class as needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it does seem that your is an X/Y problem and would be more elegantly solved using a trait such as `Default`, it is possible to match macro parameters to some extent.

Your macro could be re-written as

```rust
macro_rules! create {
    (C) => {
        Box::new(C::new()) as Box<dyn Trait>
    };

    ($type:ident) => {
        Box::new($type {}) as Box<dyn Trait>
    };
}
```

The compiler stops at the first successful match.

Note that this has some limitation: As you might expect, the compiler makes a literal comparison of tokens, and for example things like the following will fail:

```rust
type D = C;

let really_just_another_c: Box<dyn Trait> = create!(D);
```

with

```
error[E0063]: missing field `created_time` in initializer of `C`
  --> src/main.rs:41:18
   |
41 |         Box::new($type {}) as Box<dyn Trait>
   |                  ^^^^^ missing `created_time`
...
51 |     let c: Box<dyn Trait> = create!(D);
   |                             ---------- in this macro invocation
```

Comment: While indeed not the perfect solution to the problem, it does give a perfect answer to the question. Thanks.